# Dremel - repetition and definition level

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, dataset, parquet, dremel

Reading [Interactive Analysis of Web-Scale Datasets](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36632.pdf) paper, I bumped into the concept of repetition and definition level.

 while I understand the need for these two, to be able to disambiguate occurrences, it attaches a repetition and definition level to each value.

What is unclear to me is how they computed the levels...

As illustrated in picture:
[image]

It says:

> Consider ﬁeld Code in Figure 2. It occurs three times in r1. Occurrences ‘en-us’ and ‘en’ are inside the ﬁrst Name, while ’en-gb’ is in the third Name. To disambiguate these occurrences, we attach a repetition level to each value. It tells us at what repeated ﬁeld in the ﬁeld’s path the value has repeated.

---

> The ﬁeld path Name.Language.Code contains two repeated ﬁelds, Name and Language. Hence, the repetition level of Code ranges between 0 and 2; level 0 denotes the start of a new record. Now suppose we are scanning record r1 top down. When we encounter ‘en-us’, we have not seen any repeated ﬁelds, i.e., the repetition level is 0. When we see ‘en’, ﬁeld Language has repeated, so the repetitionlevelis2.

I just can't get me head around it, `Name.Language.Code` in `r1` has `en-us` and `en` values. While is the first one `r = 0` and the second one `r = 2` is it because two definitions were repeated ? (language and code) ?

If it was:

```
Name
    Language
       Code: en-us
Name 
    Language
        Code: en
Name
    Language
        Code: en-gb
```

Would it be ?

```
0 2
1 2
2 2
```

---

> Deﬁnition levels. Each value of a ﬁeld with path p, esp. every NULL, has a deﬁnition level specifying how many ﬁelds in p that could be undeﬁned (because they are optional or repeated) are actually present in record.

Why is then the definition level is 2 ?
Isn't the path `Name.Language` contain two fields `Code` and `Country` where only 1 is `optional\repeated` ?

Comment: There is another great explanation of repetition and definition levels at https://blog.twitter.com/2013/dremel-made-simple-with-parquet, it may be worth reading as well.

Comment: @Zoltan yes I've already read it. So some sentences were a bit unclear, in general it was a great explanation. I'm surprised there was no `dremel` tag before this question...

Comment: here is one more description, and no the algorithm is not trivial by any mean: https://github.com/julienledem/redelm/wiki/The-striping-and-assembly-algorithms-from-the-Dremel-paper

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Dremel striping algorithm is by no means trivial.

To answer your first question:

- The repetition level of `en-us` is 0 since it is the first occurrence of a `name.language.code` path within the record.
- The repetition level of `en` is 2, since the repetition occurred at level 2 (the language tag).

To answer your second question, for the following record,

```
DocId: 20
Name
  Language
    Code: en-us
Name 
  Language
    Code: en
Name
  Language
    Code: en-gb
```

the entries for `name.language.code` would be

```
en-us 0 2
en    1 2
en-gb 1 2
```

Explanation:

- The definition level is always two, since the two optional tags `name` and `language` are present.
- The repetition level for `en-us` is zero, since it is the first `name.language.code` within the record.
- The repetition level for `en` and `en-gb` is 1, since the repetition occurred at the `name` tag (level 1).

Comment: The question and the answer are excellent, can you give some more random example so it becomes even clearer.

Answer (score 4):

[Adelin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1170677/adelin) asked for some more random examples to make things clearer. To expand on [user152468](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2069922/user152468)'s answer:

```
DocId: 20
Name
  Language
    Code: en-us
Name 
  Language
    Code: en
Name
  Language
    Code: en-gb
  Language
    Code: zh
Name
  url: 'https://A'
```

Would be:

| Code | Repetition | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| en-us | 0 | 2 |
| en | 1 | 2 |
| en-gb | 1 | 2 |
| zh | 2 | 2 |
| NULL | 1 | 1 |

For `zh`, the definition level is 2 like the first three codes, but its repetition level is **2**. The repetition level is not the number of times an item is repeated, it is the level in the tree that is repeated. The repetition level is 2 because `Name.Language` is repeated (which is a depth of 2). `en` and `en-gb` have repetition levels of 1 because `Name` is being repeated (not `Name.Language`).

The last *NULL* in the table refers to the missing `Name.Language.Code` for the `https://A` `Name`. The repetition level is 1 since `Name` is the repeated level. The definition level is **1** because there is only 1 optional level that is defined (`Name`).

## Definition Levels

When trying to understand definition levels, it's important to know if the fields are required or optional (nullable or repeated). In the Dremel paper example, `Code` is required and `Country` is nullable. I struggled with this example for a while:

```
DocId: 20
Name
  Language
    Code: en-us
    Country: us
```

| Code | Repetition | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| en-us | 0 | 2 |

| Country | Repetition | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- |
| us | 0 | 3 |

The definition level of `en-us` is 2 because there are 2 **optional** fields that are defined: `Name` and `Language`. The code itself is required, so it isn't counted for the definition level.

The definition level of `us` is 3 because there are 3 **optional** fields in the path: `Name`, `Language`, and `Country`.

So to answer the original question:

> Why is then the definition level is 2? Isn't the path Name.Language contain two fields Code and Country where only 1 is optional\repeated?

The definition level doesn't convey how many optional fields are in the `Language` record. It conveys how many optional fields are defined in the **path**. It seems unnecessary when everything is defined, but it's useful when there are *NULL* values.

If the language record had more optional fields (Country, Direction, and Script):

```
DocId: 20
Name
  Language
    Code (required): en-us
    Country (nullable): us
    Direction (nullable): right_to_left
    Script (nullable): Latin
```

The definition levels of `Code` and `Country` wouldn't change:

| Path | Value | Repetition | Definition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `Name.Language.Code` | en-us | 0 | 2 |
| `Name.Language.Country` | us | 0 | 3 |
| `Name.Language.Direction` | right_to_left | 0 | 3 |
| `Name.Language.Script` | Latin | 0 | 3 |

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding, there is one confusing but important detail:

> The repetition level is *NOT the sequential index* of the repeated
> field within the path, but the **index of the field among the
> repeatable fields within the path**.

Obviously, the repeated field is `Name` in your example, and that makes the level 1 for those not been the first field.

The real challenge is how to designate the repeated `Links.Forwards`. The sequential index of the repeated field, `Forwards`, is 2, but since field `Links` is not repeatable, the repetition is 1, not 2.

This page helps a lot as some comments already mentioned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).